# AsDocumentQuery.HasMore Result parallelism?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, azure-cosmosdb

I have not yet faced a situation where a query for documents has more than 1 "set". I was wondering, what would happen, if instead of

```
while (queryable.HasMoreResults) 
{
    foreach(Book b in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>())
    {
        // Iterate through books
    }
}
```

i use

```
ConcurrentBag<IPost> result = new ConcurrentBag<IPost>();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
var outQ = query.AsDocumentQuery<IPost>();
while (outQ.HasMoreResults)
{
    var parcialResult = outQ.ExecuteNextAsync<IPost>().ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in t.Result)
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    });
    tasks.Add(parcialResult);
}

return Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith((r) => { return result.AsEnumerable(); });
```

I'm under the impression that the second approach, being a parallel one would yield more performance, once the partial queries would be execute concurrently... but i'm afraid that `while (outQ.HasMoreResults)` won't become false until all async ops have finished...

Comment: The last return made me chuckle. Bravo! Pretty creative way to implement an async return (exception handling would be nice, but otherwise, truly - not bad). One thing that does look icky to me though is `outQ.ExecuteNextAsync` inside a *tight* loop. You can't rely on an async call to properly set your `outQ.HasMoreResults` in time for the next loop iteration, so you are likely to end up queuing more tasks than you really need.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy this being i demo code, i omitted it, but the real deal will surely have exception handling and retry logic

Comment: I would hope that the "real deal" would also use TPL Dataflow or at least some other well-established async producer-consumer pattern (such as a classic pipeline from Microsoft's Patterns of Parallel Programming, page 55: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=19222)

Answer (score 0):

Your concern regarding `HasMoreResults` not updating quickly enough is well-founded. You cannot dispatch an async operation and assume the object will immediately transition to the state expected of it at the *end* of the async operation. In this particular case you have no choice but to *wait* for the async operation to complete.

I assume that the library authors deliberately chose the API which does not lend itself to parallelisation - most likely because it encapsulates the kind of work which needs to be done serially.